# SQL Server - Quarterly data Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I have recently wrote a query (stack overflow helped) to generate annual data from a database. 
the logic used is : any day in this year will always give all the results from last year.

`where year (table.datecolumn) = year(GETDATE())-1`

Now, I have been asked to do a similar thing with quarterly data and I am having a hard time as I am not very experienced in writing these kinds of queries.

I want something that I can schedule a **ssrs report** with- that gives me all the **data for each quarter without using real dates.** so that I could schedule this to run on Jan 1st, April 1st, July 1st, Oct 1st.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `DATEPART(qq,Datecolumn)` that will show quarter of your date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is query to get all data for the previous quarter

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE MyDate >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
        AND MyDate < DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This way you can run it any time after the next quarter starts and before it ends it will still produce same results without having to specify dates.